# Tabs in the elements of Zoo Joomla Component

Tags: cck, zoo-cck

We want to use Tabs in the elements of Joomla Zoo Component.

We want to evaluate tabs in the Edit and Submission and Full and Teaser Views of the Zoo Component.

We are using JU Tabs Tabs Extension for Joomla 3.

JU Tabs Homepage:

http://www.joomultra.com/joomla-extensions/8/132/joomla-extensions/P-ju-tabs.html

We have coded a new Element Named TextSeparator

Which is used to run the system plugins such as JU Tabs in the frontend (Edit, Submission And Full And Teaser Views).

We added the Text Separator Element Code link below:

https://s24.picofile.com/file/8451491092/joomla_root.zip.html

As mentioned in the Picture Below :

[image: Screen Capture]

As you can see we have this structure for elements :

```
Tab 001 – New Tab

     Text Field 001

Tab 002 – New Tab

     Text Field 002

Tab 003 – Close
```

But with this method the tabs are rendered in this way in frontend while editing Zoo Item:

[image]

[image]

As you can see all of the Text fields are rendered in each tab, but we included just one Text Field in each tab in design section of Zoo Elements.

How can we fix this?

Also we want a facility to hide the Element Label while editing the Zoo item in Frontend.